# Talend Tmysql Component to run stored procedure?

Tags: talend

I know there are tmysqlrow and tmysqlsp components available in Talend but it is fine if we use tmysqlinput to run stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements but generally you can use all of those components.

```
tMysqlSP
```

is there for convenience.

```
tMySqlRow
```

allows much more freedom.

```
tMySqlInput
```

is usually being used to get a result from the database. If you stored procedure doesn't return rows, which is sometimes the case, the following elements of the job might not run then.

So I would use one of the two first ones.